# Integrate Vue application inside angular js application

Tags: angularjs, vue.js

I have a vue application, I have created a build using webpack, now the build index.html and static folder I have copied in my Angular js application inside src by renaming my vue index.html so that different framework's html should not conflict.

Now in one of the Angular html file I have added my vue html file using 'ng-include' directive.

Vue Application gets loaded but router-view is not working and that all components that renders under router is not loading

I tried to add VueRouter cdn in my angularjs index.html, this gives me this error in console

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $router

Comment: I am not very familiar with Angular, however, I believe Angular is first defining a $router variable in the global scope so the VueRouter $router variable is in conflict.